# Azure AD - Location based

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cloud-services

Good Afternoon,

Here is the scenario, our company manages multiple computers/pcs (about 50 or so) that are located in different geographic locations.  These 50 computers run the same software locally.  They all connect to a Apache Linux Box that is housed on premises.  They are all in a workgroup locally. Something like this:

- Location 1 (Term1, Term2, Term3, Term4, etc.)
- Location 2 (Term1, Term2, Term3, etc.)
- Location 3 (Term1, Term2, etc.)
- Location 4 (Term1, Term2, Term3, Term4, Term5, etc.)

As mentioned, all the computers run in a workgroup. A local user is defined for each computer. Say user1/user2/user3/etc. We have to maintain a list of users since user management has become a bear as we have grown. In addition, patch management has become very time consuming as well. Traditional Active Directory (on-premise) is not an option as the clients at each location are different people with different financial resources and most/none are willing purchase/maintain Windows Server on premise.

The basic thought being, if it is not broke, don't fix it. As far as the user is concerned, they are not seeing a problem because most only have to deal with 4/5 computers in each location.

I noticed that in Windows 10, there is a an Azure AD service support. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light as to how that would work and how many users I would have to setup as to control costs.  Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at Microsoft Intune for client management: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/microsoft-intune/Features.aspx

And more specifically: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn646959.aspx

Answer (score -1):

With Windows 10 you are able to manage the user identities in Azure AD and the computers can to a domain join into Azure. At the same time you can set this up so that the devices also is auto-enrolled into Microsoft Intune for management when they join AzureAD.

This will allow you to manage settings and policies on the Windows 10 machines and control Windows Updates and Windows Defender.

This is just a very short description of the possibilities within Azure AD with Windows 10, and even more is coming this summer with the Aniversary Release of Windows 10.